# Multiple queries inside Insert command in HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

In my use case, I need to do something like this,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test 
  select
      count(*) where recordedValue < 0,
      count(*) where recordedValue > 0 and recordedValue < 10,
      count(*) where recordedValue > 10 and recordedValue < 20
   from sample
```

Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: you need 3 columns based on condition????

Comment: Yes.. Infact, i put only 3 out of 40 !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test 
select count(col1), count(col2), count(col3) From (
select 
CASE WHEN recordedValue < 0 THEN recordedValue END as col1,
CASE WHEN recordedValue > 0 AND recordedValue < 10 THEN recordedValue END as col2,
CASE WHEN recordedValue > 10 AND recordedValue < 20 THEN recordedValue END as col3 
from sample ) a;
```

first check select statement;

Comment: I get the error Expression not in GROUP BY key '0'. However, if i replace count(*) with some integer, it works.